# Distinct is not working in crystal reports and in mysql

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

```
id_no    doc_id    item_no   product    customer
123        2         1         A        Daisy
123        2         9         A        Ben
123        4         3         A        Daisy
123        4         4         A        Ben
123        6        11         B        Daisy
123        6        13         B        Ben
```

when I put it in my report it results to

```
Daisy     Daisy   
Ben
```

And it is also the result in mysql

```
select distinct customer from receipt where id_no like '123'

result:
Daisy
Daisy        
Ben
```

Another query that I tried:

```
select distinct id_no, customer, product from receipt where id_no like '123'

result:
123       Daisy   A
123       Daisy   B
123       Daisy   A
123       Ben     A
123       Ben     B
```

desired result: 
Daisy 
Ben

Please help me please.

**Thank you guys for the help I found out why the other one keeps on showing. It is because the other Daisy is spelled as Daissy that's why.**

Comment: I assume the distinct in Crystal Reports is also on customer, just like in your mysql sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your Customer name contains additional characters between the two records. Depending on how the datatype is implemented, spaces could matter and have contributed to the difference.
Try concatenating a character before and after `customer`.

I am unfamiliar with the concepts in Crystal Reports, but from what I understand, you would have to create a formula like so:

```
"XXX" & {Receipt.Customer} & "XXX"
```

If you run it again, you might recognize there is additional space like so:

```
XXXDaisyXXX
XXXDaisy XXX
        ^____ Additional Space
```

Comment: I found out why it shows 2 Daisy because the other data is spelled Daissy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Haha good one - copy-paste error into your Original Post. Well happens to me too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance of error while you using distinct ..it should return distinct value ...any way you can try another way

```
SELECT customer FROM receipt WHERE id_no like '123' GROUP BY customer
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you are fetching three records. I tried implementing your database and ran your query. It returned the result as expected.

[image]

See the above pic. There may be some issue with the data type you used. You may try grouping via customer, but I don't think it should affect your result anyway.

Also Check if the data types match.

The selection you made from customer id and id_no is unique and with distinct it should return only two rows

Comment: Thanks for the effort in answering my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

plase try this code
i get solution

```
select distinct `customer` from receipt where `id_no`='123'
```

this is right
i tryied this is my past project
best of luck